# Is there a centralized achievement system for browserbased onlinegames

Tags: browser-based-games, achievements, community-management

I plan to implement missions with achievements (or rewards/badges) in my online space browser game [spacetrace](http://www.spacetrace.org).

I want somehow connect that to an existing online achievement platform for browser-based HTML5-games?

There are some online platforms that lets users show their achievements in several games they have reached like GameCenter, OpenFeint, Steam, PlaystationNetwork and [Scoreloop](http://www.scoreloop.com/)

But is there a great community for browser-based onlinegames too?

[clay.io](http://clay.io) looks quite promising.

Which is the most used platform that I should implement the achievements on?

Answer (score 4):

[Kongregate](http://www.kongregate.com/) have an [achievement system](http://developers.kongregate.com/docs/api-overview/intro). It works a lot like Steam, so you can get multiple achievements from different games on different platforms (Flash, Unity, etc.) and you can show them off.

Sign up for an account and play a game that has achievements to see how it works. Kongregate is also an incredibly popular online community, so your game will also get lots of exposure.

**UPDATE** Here is a link to [Kongregate's API](http://developers.kongregate.com/docs/api-overview/client-api) section for developers. Completely slipped my mind to include the link. That should help you out with implementation.

Comment: That platform looks fine, but it seems, like you can only upload your flash game there. I already have a running online game in HTML5 on [www.spacetrace.org](http://www.spacetrace.org)

Comment: @rubo77 Kongregate has Flash, Unity, and HTML5 games. http://www.kongregate.com/html5-games

Comment: Ah cool, I see. And it seems, it is possible just to add our browsergame, that is hosted on my server there. Just a strange "Upload" form (I won't really upload an Iframe there)

Answer (score 4):

Google has [announced](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.com/2013/05/introducing-google-play-game-services.html) its [Google Play game services](https://developers.google.com/games/services/) which offer

- Achievements
- Leaderboards
- Cloud Save
- Matchmaking

across Android, iOS, and web (via RESTful apis).

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer: I am a co-founder of [Clay.io](http://clay.io) (mentioned in question).

Since January we've added search and made the site a bit less cluttered, here are some useful links to look through.

[Developer Info Page](http://clay.io/development-tools)
[Documentation](http://clay.io/docs)
[Achievements Documentation](http://clay.io/docs/achievements)

I hope this helps. You hit the nail on the head for the platforms we're emulating, only for HTML5 games. One more that's similar is Mochi Media (for Flash Games). As mentioned, Kongregate and now Google Play are alternatives.